# Apply patch to Macbook Pro 11,4 to fix Power/Suspend

Tags: kernel, suspend, shutdown, macbook, macbook-pro

I have successfully installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my 15" Macbook Pro mid-2015. Currently, shutting down and suspending does not work, but I found this patch [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=103211#c172) that applies a patch to the kernel. I pasted the code given there

```
diff --git a/drivers/pci/quirks.c b/drivers/pci/quirks.c
index ee72ebe..d3ec833 100644
--- a/drivers/pci/quirks.c
+++ b/drivers/pci/quirks.c
@@ -2775,6 +2775,13 @@ static void quirk_hotplug_bridge(struct pci_dev *dev)

 DECLARE_PCI_FIXUP_HEADER(PCI_VENDOR_ID_HINT, 0x0020, quirk_hotplug_bridge);

+static void quirk_hotplug_bridge_skip(struct pci_dev *dev)
+{
+       dev->is_hotplug_bridge = 0;
+}
+
+DECLARE_PCI_FIXUP_HEADER(PCI_VENDOR_ID_INTEL, 0x8c10,
quirk_hotplug_bridge_skip);
+
 /*
  * This is a quirk for the Ricoh MMC controller found as a part of
  * some mulifunction chips.
```

into a file that I named patch.diff and I placed it in my Downloads directory. I then navigated to `/usr/src/linux-headers-######` and typed the command `patch -p1 < ~/Downloads/patch.diff`, however this tells me that there is no quirks.c file available. Is the quirks.c file supposed to be there? How do I create one? I really want to fix suspend and power off, because those are the only problems with Ubuntu now.

Note: I replaced a and b in the directory names in the patch file with `..`. I'm also using kernel 4.5.2

Comment: Did you see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/672750/standby-and-shutdown-hang-on-macbook-pro-11-4)?