# Problems with sleep mode and shutdown

Tags: 16.04, suspend, shutdown

I use ubuntu 16.04 Lts on a macbook pro with an intel integrated gpu and a Radeon HD 8870M. I use the radeon driver and can't update it in the update menu.When the computer goes into sleep mode it doesn't come out of this mode when I press the power button or any other key. I read in some posts that it could be solved by updating the video driver but I can't because the only driver I can choose is an unknown driver that displays as being "radeon" when I use the terminal.

My second problem is when I select the shutdown option everything goes normally until the dots freeze but when I choose to restart I don't have any problems.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: This is a [known issue with the Linux Kernel](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=104611) that occurs on both MacbookPro11,5 (discrete video) and MacbookPro11,4 (no discrete video). There's a patch [available for Arch Linux](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/linux-macbook), but I haven't found a way to apply that patch in Ubuntu yet.

Comment: I found the answer in [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/672750/standby-and-shutdown-hang-on-macbook-pro-11-4?rq=1).